# How to correctly pass an integer variable from one function to another in Python3 and PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

**EDIT**
I've updated my code below to what I think is correct however I'm still not getting the desired output, I've also included how both fucntions are called within my mainWindow class...

I'm having issues passing an integer between two functions in my GUI program shown below. I'm using Python3.7 and pyqt5.

```
     def capture_duration(self, item):#recieves file list item from file_list
        fn = item.text() #extract text data of file, ie file name
        url = qtc.QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.video_dir.filePath(fn)) #get URL of file
        print(url) #unforunately PyQt5 doesn't give a clean file path to hand to openCV
        url = url.toString() #convert 'URL' to string
        url.strip("PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl('/") #strip string of everything before the C.
        print(url) #print for testing only
        data = cv2.VideoCapture(url) #start video capture with openCV
        frames = data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) #get number of frames of video
        fps = int(data.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)) #get fps of video
        duration = int(frames/fps) #compute frames/fps for total duration in seconds
        print("Duration of video is:", duration) #print for test purposes only.
        return duration

    def imgacq(self, duration):#FPS of camera averages 54FPS
        print('Duration is', duration)
        num_frames = (duration*54) #duration of video in seconds multiplied by recording frame rate of camera.
        print(num_frames)
        with Camera() as cam:
            if 'Bayer' in cam.PixelFormat:
                cam.PixelFormat = 'RGB8'

        cam.OffsetX = 0
        cam.OffsetY = 0
        cam.Width = cam.SensorWidth
        cam.Height = cam.SensorHeight

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Opened camera %s (#%s), now recording...' % (cam.DeviceModelName, cam.DeviceSerialNumber))
        cam.start()
        start = time.time()

        imgs = [cam.get_array() for n in range(num_frames)] #num frames must = number of frames in selected video.

        el = time.time() - start
        cam.stop()

        print('Acquired %d images in %.2f s (~ %.1f fps)' % (len(imgs), el, len(imgs) / el))

        # Make a directory to save some images
        output_dir = 'test_images'
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)

        print('Saving to "%s"' % output_dir)

        # Save them
        for n, img in enumerate(imgs):
            Image.fromarray(img).save(os.path.join(output_dir, '%08d.jpg' % n))
```

Both functions are called within my mainWindow class as follows, where `capture_duration` starts when an video file is clicked in a file viewer and `imgacq` starts when a play button on a toolbar is clicked:

```
self.file_list.itemClicked.connect(self.capture_duration)
play_action.triggered.connect(self.imgacq)
```

When I run this 'duration' is printed correctly as an integer in 'capture_duration' but when passed to 'imgacq' it is printed as `False` rather than the specific integer value. My logic for this code is that `capture_duration` inherits some information from mainWindow class, does a computation and returns `duration`. `imgacq` then inherits `duration` and uses it accordingly, however it clearly isn't working that way.

I'm sure this is a very basic error that I'm making but I'm stuck and would really appreciate any help!

Comment: `secs = self.capture_duration()` add those parentheses there, that just may be the issue, otherwise You are not calling that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that `imagecq` is printing False is because the signal `play_action.triggered` emits the `checked` state of the action (which is False). This is then assigned to the input parameter of `imagecq`: `duration`.

Another issue is that Qt widgets ignore any output generated by slots, so the returned value of `capture_duration` will be lost when the slot is triggered. One option to resolve this is to assign the value of `duration` to a non-local variable like for example an instance variable instead of (or in addition to) returning it. So in your case you could do something like:

```
def capture_duration(self, item):#recieves file list item from file_list
    ....
    self.duration = duration
    return duration   # this return value will be ignored if capture_duration is used as a slot so could be omitted
```

And then in `imagcq`:

```
# Note: input parameter has been omitted. instance variable is used instead
def imgacq(self):   
    duration = self.duration
    .....
```

In addition you need to initialize `self.duration` to some sensible value before the main window is shown to prevent an error when `imacq` is called before `capture_duration`.

Comment: Thank you for the concise and detailed answer, you've solved my issue which I've been struggling with for days and have most likely just ensured that I will actually pass my dissertation, TYVM :)